# Trace/clip a segment of a line using a point layer

Tags: qgis, network, snapping, route, points-to-line

I have a set of points as well as a line layer (a road network) as given below.

[image: Point and line layers]

After I snap the points to the line layer the result is as follows.

[image: Points snapped to lines]

The result that I need is to clip/trace the line layer segment spanning the point layer like this:

[image: Traced line layer]

I've tried many methods on QGIS from using a buffer on the snap points to clip, to using join attributes by nearest/location, however due to the inconsistency of the placement of the points on the line layer I always end up with many gaps, unnecessary segments. I am also unable to use the points to path feature because the points don't have an attribute which indicates order.

What's the best way that I could try to achieve this result? I'm willing to even venture into solutions outside of QGIS (GRASS, GeoPandas) as long as it's open source.

Comment: You could add the ascending ID manually?

Comment: Without having your data this is impossible to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Network tools. Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Shortest Path (point to layer)` (see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#shortest-path-point-to-layer)) with these settings:

- as `Vector layer representing network`, use your line layer.
- for `Start Point`, click on the first point (use activated snapping to "catch" the point)
- for `Vector layer with end points`, use your points layer - no need to snap them to the line beforehand.

However, you need a proper network: where lines intersect or touch, they must have a common vertex for the tool to find a connection between lines. Alternatively, expand `Advanced Parameters` and set a (small) topology tolerence.

When you run the tool, you get the desired output - see screenshot below.

*Be aware: If you want to clean the result, [explode the lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) and [delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries). If necessary, [re-merge](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#merge-selected-features) the lines and convert from [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) to get simple lines as output.*

*Screenshot: yellow lines created based on black input network and red points:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I seem to end up with many extra segments: https://imgur.com/V5HZfnY

Comment: From the Image it does not become clear which lines are Desiree outputs and which not. Can you add details? Can you share Project + data?